# How to read compiler error

Tags: haskell

I wrote an implementation of Monad for custom type:

```
  data Sum a b =
      First a
    | Second b
    deriving (Eq, Show)

  instance Functor (Sum a) where
    fmap _ (First x) = First x
    fmap f (Second y) = Second (f y)

  instance Applicative (Sum a) where
    pure = Second
    First x <*> _ = First x
    _ <*> First x = First x 
    Second f <*> Second x = Second (f x)

  instance Monad (Sum a) where
    return = pure
    (First a) >>= _ = First a
    (Second a) >>= k = Second (k a)
```

and I know it is wrong. The compiler complains:

```
D:\haskell\chapter18\src\SumMonad.hs:39:24: error:
    * Couldn't match type `b' with `Sum a b'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a1 b. Sum a a1 -> (a1 -> Sum a b) -> Sum a b
        at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\SumMonad.hs:38:15
      Expected type: Sum a b
        Actual type: Sum a (Sum a b)
    * In the expression: Second (k a)
      In an equation for `>>=': (Second a) >>= k = Second (k a)
      In the instance declaration for `Monad (Sum a)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        k :: a1 -> Sum a b
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\SumMonad.hs:39:20)
        (>>=) :: Sum a a1 -> (a1 -> Sum a b) -> Sum a b
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\SumMonad.hs:38:5)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How to read the compiler error?

Answer (score 11):

```
* Couldn't match type `b' with `Sum a b'
```

Translation: I (the compiler) expected a `b` and got a `Sum a b` instead.

```
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (>>=) :: forall a1 b. Sum a a1 -> (a1 -> Sum a b) -> Sum a b
```

Translation: Because of the signature of `>>=` the concrete type value of the type variable `b` can't be choosen by you, but by your caller. You can't just hand me any kind of value and expect `b` to take the type of your expression as its type value (remember `b` is a type variable).

```
  Expected type: Sum a b
    Actual type: Sum a (Sum a b)
```

Translation: To make it easier for you, I hand you a little bit more context. I expected a `Sum a b` and you handed me a `Sum a (Sum a b)`. You can now already see, that the problem is here in bold

```
      (>>=) :: forall a1 b. Sum a a1 -> (a1 -> Sum a b) -> Sum a b
```

because that is the type of the values your implementation of that function should produce.

```
* In the expression: Second (k a)
  In an equation for `>>=': (Second a) >>= k = Second (k a)
  In the instance declaration for `Monad (Sum a)'
```

More context for you. I (the compiler) don't like the expression

```
 Second (k a)
```

in the equation

```
 (Second a) >>= k = Second (k a)
```

here you can infer, that `Second (k a)` has type `Sum a (Sum a b)` instead of `Sum a b`.

And even more helpful messages for you:

```
* Relevant bindings include
    k :: a1 -> Sum a b
      (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\SumMonad.hs:39:20)
    (>>=) :: Sum a a1 -> (a1 -> Sum a b) -> Sum a b
      (bound at D:\haskell\chapter18\src\SumMonad.hs:38:5)
```

Translation: The result of `k a` already is a `Sum a b`, you see? So if you think of my former (hopefully helpful messages), `Second (k a)` will be of type `Sum a (Sum a b)`, which is not `Sum a b` as I already told you.